# MapXtreme Java Edition

Tags: mapxtreme

I'm learning GIS in Java with MapXtreme Java Edition but I can't find MapXtreme Java Edition file setup for Window (trial). Can you share link download or software for me ? Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Download from [here](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/by-product/mapinfo-mapxtreme-java/) .

And the developer guide is [here](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapxtreme_java/english/4_8/MapXtremeJavaDeveloperGuide.pdf).

Good luck.